# RPA Express (Workfusion) Web Element seting a checkbox

Tags: checkbox, rpa, workfusion

I am new to RPA Express (Workfusion) and I can't figure out how to set a checkbox to true using Web Element - set by xpath. 
What needs to be pun into a variable to set a checkbox to CHECKED status?

I can't use Click Mouse function as it would toggle the status while my goal is to ensure that a checkbox is set to TRUE always.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Use the Web Element

   - get mode
   - tick **Use element attribute**
   - type **checked**
   - select a variable for Output
2. If the Output variable is true -> do nothing
3. If the Output variable is false -> click the checkbox

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This is a work-around that complicates the code somewhat (need for additional IF). I am pretty sure there must be some direct way

Comment: Besides if chechbox is not checked an error is thrown:PlaybackException: Error executing TemplateAction[templateName=WebElementAction.ftl,id=65,name=Optional[WebElementAction],parent=-8,nextSibling=66,arguments=ActionArguments[varName=[set_value],elementAttribute=[checked],exactMatch=[true],xsi:type=[recorder:WebElementAction, recorder:WebElementAction],pollingInterval=[300],active=[true],searchInFrames=[false],delay=[0],useElementAttribute=[true],webElementLocatorType=[XPATH],actionDetails=[(get by //*[@id="cRefCompany"] xpath)],webElementLocator=[//*[@id="cRefCompany"]],awaitTimeout=[5000]]]